# How can I acheve exclusion control in nodejs

Tags: node.js, concurrency, mutex, semaphore

I'm working on creating a chat app in which node.js server counts up the number of characters of all messages. For instance, 100 people sending messages each of them having the length of 10 means that total character count is 1000(100 * 10). And if a person sends a message with the length of 10 after that, total character count should be 1010(1000 + 10).

All messages are sent to node.js server, counted its length and saved on DB.

A big problem occurred when a lot of people send messages at the same time.

When I send 100 messages each of them having the length of 10 (like the example above) **AT THE SAME TIME** by jMeter, total character count was 120. It is supposed to be exact 1000!

Here's my code(node version 8.13.0):

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const co = require('co');
const models = require('models');
const Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;
const CharacterCounter = models.CharacterCounter;

router.get('/message', function (req, res, next) {
  co(function* () {
    const originalText = req.body.message;

    const mutex = new Mutex();

    const release = yield mutex.acquire();
    let addedCount = 0;
    try {
      const { currentCount } = yield CharacterCounter.findOne(); // get total character count so far
      addedCount = currentCount + originalText.length;
      yield CharacterCounter.updateTotalCharacterCount(addedCount); // save on DB
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      release();
    }

    // ... my code is keep going
```

It seems that the cause of this problem is in mutex library. But I don't know the exact solution. Does anyone have an idea to achieve my goal? I've only started working on node.js recently, so a plain explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const co = require('co');
const models = require('models');
const Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;
const CharacterCounter = models.CharacterCounter;

const mutex = new Mutex();

router.get('/message', function (req, res, next) {
  co(function* () {
    const originalText = req.body.message;


    const release = yield mutex.acquire();
    let addedCount = 0;
    try {
      const { currentCount } = yield CharacterCounter.findOne(); // get total character count so far
      addedCount = currentCount + originalText.length;
      yield CharacterCounter.updateTotalCharacterCount(addedCount); // save on DB
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      release();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to explain how it works?